# Is there a way to hide the identity of the transaction issuer in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

one of my current use-case requirement is to hide the identity of the transaction invoker in hyperledger fabric v1.1 GA version

the use-case require that the data are share in a "public" channel while wanting to hide the identity of the transaction invoker.

my current thought is to have a "broker" peer in which this broker peer will have a bilateral private channel with all the other peers in the system (i.e. if there are 5 peers / organization, then there will be 5 bilateral channel between each of the peer with the broker. As well, every peer (include the broker) will be member of the public channel.

instead of invoking transaction directly to the public channel, the peer will invoke transaction into the private channel with the "broker" peer. the broker peer then relay the action by invoking the transaction on the public channel. thus the transaction signature will be of the broker.

with this the broker will act as the "middleman" which is kind of beat the purpose of having a distributed system.

Is there any other possibility to achieve the desired result of hiding the identity of the transaction invoker?

Answer (score 1):

Read about [identity mixer](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/idemix.html) - it allows you to sign transactions anonymously via generating a pseudonym upon each transaction signing and it uses non interactive zero knowledge proofs to prove that you have a private key issued by the CA of the MSP you belong to.

Comment: noted with thank.  my understanding is identity mixer is in tech. review mode for HLF 1.1 and we would like to go with HLF 1.1 GA version.

Comment: You should go with the latest Fabric version and not with v1.1 . The current latest version is v1.2

Comment: upon reading the id mixer documentation (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/idemix.html) what i understand is that within a CA, the linkability between user and credential can be hide.

however, if knowing that a particular certificate is generated from a particular CA (which map to an organization), then eventhough the transaction cannot be attribute to a particular user, but still can be attribute to a particular organization.

in such case, how can we fully anonymize the transaction (hiding both the user who generate the transaction and the organization)